# How to call promise function in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, reducers

I am call a promise function in my reducer, so I call it like this:

```
cart(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    //...
    case LOG_IN:
        return getCartProducts(true)
    }
}


getCartProducts(isLogin) {
    // ....
    return cartApi.list({
            customerId: "",
            items: items
        }).then(data => {
            return cartReduce(undefined, receiveCartProducts(data.items, false))
        })
}
```

so this just returns a promise, not the object I want to

Comment: Reducers are supposed to be pure, you shouldn't be requesting stuff there.

Comment: @QoP so if I want to listen to `LOG_IN` action, how can I do?

Comment: Take a look at redux-thunk as one possible mechanism of managing async requests. You basically fire multiple actions to represent the async request state. Also highly recommend you read the official redux docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should make async actions for these as described [in the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators).

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

// One action to tell your app you're fetching data
export const GET_CART_PRODUCTS_REQUEST = 'GET_CART_PRODUCTS_REQUEST'
function getCartProductsRequest(customerId) {
  return {
    type: GET_CART_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
    customerId
  };
}

// One action to signify success
export const GET_CART_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'GET_CART_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS'
function getCartProductsSuccess(cartProducts) {
  return {
    type: GET_CART_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    cartProducts
  };
};

// One action to signify an error
export const GET_CART_PRODUCTS_ERROR = 'GET_CART_PRODUCTS_ERROR'
function getCartProductsSuccess(error) {
  return {
    type: GET_CART_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
    error
  };
};

// This is the async action that fires one action when it starts
// And then one of two actions when it finishes
export function fetchCartProducts(customerId) {
  return dispatch => {
    // Dispatch action that tells your app you're going to get data
    // This is where you'll set any 'isLoading' state in your store
    dispatch(getCartProductsRequest(customerId))

    return fetch('https://api.website.com/customers/' + customerId + '/cartProducts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        // Fire success action on success
        cartProducts => dispatch(getCartProductsSuccess(cartProducts)),

        // Fire error action on error
        error => dispatch(getCartProductsError(error))
      );
    };
  };
}
```